# Java Tree Implementation

Tags: java, tree, generics

I wrote a simple tree data type in Java consisting of nodes which are themselves trees, and where each tree has its own list of children (not a binary tree). I plan on eventually using it in a minimax algorithm where I keep track of future game states in a board game by holding different board states in nodes and holding moves that lead to each state as edges in the tree. Here's my code so far — any suggestions (whether it be conceptual or performance related, or other features I should add) are appreciated:

```
public class Tree<V, E> {
   private V data;
   //here the edgeVal is the edge leading from the node's parent to the node itself,
   //not from the node to any of its children
   private E edgeVal;
   private Tree<V, E> parent;
   private ArrayList<Tree<V, E>> children;
   public Tree(V data, Tree<V, E> parent, E edgeVal) {
      this.data = data;
      this.edgeVal = edgeVal;
      this.parent = parent;
      this.children = new ArrayList<Tree<V, E>>();
   }
   public void addChild(V childData, E edgeVal) {
      Tree<V, E> child = new Tree<V, E>(childData, this, edgeVal);
      this.children.add(child);
   }
   public Tree<V, E> getParent() {
      return this.parent;
   }
   public ArrayList<Tree<V, E>> getChildren() {
      return this.children;
   }
   public V getData() {
      return this.data;
   }
   public E getEdgeVal() {
      return this.edgeVal;
   }
   public boolean isRoot() {
      return this.parent == null;
   }
   public boolean isLeaf() {
      return this.children.size() == 0;
   }
   public String toString() {
      //assuming type of data has a nicely defined toString() method
      return this.data.toString();
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in game modelling, but I wonder if it is correct to assume the data structure is a *tree*. In some games a sequence of moves can lead to the same position. That leads to an infinite loop in a game and an infinite tree in strategy, which may be truncated by game rules (in chess, the same position for a third time ends the game) or may be not (I suppose, not all checkers variants do have such terminating rule).

Comment: True if I were doing chess or checkers (I was a bit misleading when I said "board game") -- I'm actually using it for a game of Tron, where moving back to a space that you or your opponent has occupied makes you lose, so don't think I can hit an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Code Review!

1. `isLeaf` compares the Size of children, a solution that is better readable is to use `isEmpty()` instead of compare the size of children.
2. The tree avoid a serialization that others may support, add the serializable-interface to keep serialization support.
3. `edgeVal` and `data` have no setter and to add `final` would help to avoid sideeffects whenever the code changes.
4. To have a `ArrayList` as a list of children has the problem that

   - The ArrayList can contain `null`
   - The ArrayList can contain one element twice (i do not think its a case you like to have)

   You better use some kind of set, a `LinkedHashSet` in example.
5. You can use `getChildren()` to have read-write-access to the children, if you do `oscar.getChildren().add(oscar);` your loop is perfect but not a Tree. Use the unmodifyable-functions of the class `Collections` to return a readonly-collection.
6. The class is named `Tree` that can contains a list of `Tree`. Even if a Tree can be a parasite to other Trees i propose to name the Class `TreeNode`.
7. `toString` should describe the node, not the data inside.
8. Am i the only one who write javadoc?